# Bind dynamic file contents in array format to jtable

Tags: arrays, dynamic, csv, jquery-jtable

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 3, and wondering how to return the contents of a file, as an array to a jtable in a view.  Each line of the array contains a comma separated list.  (The contents of the file came from either a .csv file or excel spreadsheet)

The first column contains the field headers, and the number of field headers in the file can vary, so I guess you could say the contents of the jtable would be dynamic?

I've written jtables with explicitly named fields, but that's when I know how many fields to expect.  In this case, it could be anywhere from 1 to 11 fields, and since the field names are in the first line of the array, i'm not quite sure how to setup the jtable to recognize them as column headers for the jtable.

For starters, here's a couple of examples of an array I would expect to bind to the table.

```
array[0] = "phone,first,last";
array[1] = "1111111111,firstname,lastname";
```

OR

```
array[0] = "first,last,email";
array[1] = "firstname,lastname,emailaddress@email.com";
```

For the first example, I would not need to display the 'email' field, and for the second I don't need the phone field.  The actual contents would probably contain many lines, which is why I want to bind it to jtable with paging enabled.

In my controller method, I have the contents of the file as a string array, one line with comma separated fields per array item.  Where do I go from there is the question.

Thanks for any help,
Carrie

Actually, I've solved my first problem by using the Expando object, to create a list of dynamic objects . . . problem now is that jtable seems to need to bind to the results returned from a post.  The json object i now have has already been returned, so I don't need to do a post to get it.  So, the question now is, is it possible to bind a json result to a jtable without making jtable do the post?

Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Working on a similar question; I am returning json and need to bind to jtable. Here is the code from within my ajax call. The only jtable method I found is the addRecord.

Hope this helps and I will edit as I improve and get this fully functional. Yeh, I know that I should only include well formed answers but since you have had no help, we can start with this and let it be a work in progress.

```
if (data.Result == "OK") {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.Records.length; i++) {
                        $("#SearchResultsAddContact").jtable('addRecord', {
                            record: {
                                FirstName: data.Records[i].FirstName,
                                LastName: data.Records[i].LastName,
                                NumGroups: data.Records[i].NumGroups,
                                NumPhones: data.Records[i].NumPhones,
                                NumTexts: data.Records[i].NumTexts,
                                NumTags: data.Records[i].NumTags,
                                NumTDDs: data.Records[i].NumTDDs,
                                NumEmails: data.Records[i].NumEmails
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    $("#SearchResultsAddContact").jtable('load');
```

Make sure that you edit your jquery.jtable.js file as follows: (lines 1297-1308)

```
    addRecord: function (options) {
        var self = this;
        options = $.extend({
            **clientOnly: true,**
            animationsEnabled: self.options.animationsEnabled,
            url: self.options.actions.createAction,
            success: function () { },
            error: function () { }
        }, options);
```

Change the clientOnly: to true